# Clustering given "distance" matrix and K in python

Tags: clustering, python, distance

INPUT ($D$, $K$):

I have a symmetrical "distance" matrix $D$ of size $N \times N$ which tells me how distant one object is from another. Function used for calculating the distances is not a metric (doesn't
satisfy triangle inequality). The values in $D$ are from $[0,1]$ where 0 means 2 objects are identical, and 1 means they are the furthest possible.

I also know that I would like to obtain $K$ clusters.

OUTPUT:

I would like to obtain $K$ clusters, where every clustroid has a small average distance to every other guy within the same cluster. Ideally with no silly clusters with 1-2 elements.

QUESTION:

Which clustering method would you use? K-means requires feature vectors, which I don't have, Spectral Clustering assumes that the distance function is a metric. I thought of using DBSCAN, but it doesn't allow $K$ as input. I could tune the hyperparams to get the $K$ I want, but I was wondering if there is a clear better choice. $N$ can range from 5 000 to 20 000, and $K$ is smaller than 1 000, so I assume there will be no issues with CPU or MEM.

Comment: How about hierarchical clustering? See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering

Comment: Spectral clustering does not require a metric. It only requires symmetry, but the triangle inequality may be violated. In https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.spectral_clustering.html you need to provide the affinity matrix, not the distance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

There are different clustering options that work well with a distance matrix and most of them accept the number of clusters as input. I list all the ones I used for my Ph.D. thesis and know they work as intended:

- **Scikit-learn's Spectral clustering:** You can transform your distance matrix to an affinity matrix following the logic of similarity, which is `(1-distance)`. The closer it gets to 1, the higher the similarity (affinity) and vice-versa. For this and the other clustering methods, if you have a 1D array, you can transform it using `sp.spatial.distance.squareform` for input to the `cluster.fit_predict` method. You need to set the `affinity` parameter to `precomputed` to work. Following the documentation, you can also use `precomputed_nearest_neighbors` for the `affinity` parameter, as a distance matrix can be interpreted as a sparse graph of precomputed distances. In my experiments, this approach yielded the best results (with external CVIs over 0.9), so it is worth mentioning.
- **Scikit-learn-extra's K-Medoids clustering:** You need to install the scikit-learn-extra library (it is not included in the standard one) to access a method similar to K-Means that can take a distance matrix as direct input. You have to set the `metric` parameter as `precomputed` and introduce the distance matrix in the `cluster.fit_predict` method for the clustering to work.
- **Scikit-learn's Agglomerative clustering:** Similar to the previous clustering methods, you need to set the `affinity` parameter to `precomputed` and use the distance matrix for the `cluster.fit_predict` method. For clarification, while we are using the `affinity` parameter (which other clustering methods use for the affinity/similarity matrix) the API indicates it takes a distance matrix instead, so no further changes are needed.
- **Hdbscan's HDBSCAN clustering:** The hierarchical version of DBSCAN accepts the distance matrix by setting the `metric` parameter to `precomputed` and using it for the `cluster.fit_predict` method. As a side note, if you need to specify the number of clusters, you can use the `flat.HDBSCAN_flat` method included in the library, which is handy as default DBSCAN and HDBSCAN do not currently support specifying the clusters as parameters.
- **Scikit-learn's Affinity Propagation clustering:** While the API does not explicitly indicates it, you need to use an affinity (similarity) matrix instead of your distance matrix for the `cluster.fit_predict` method. You can follow the recommendation from Spectral Clustering method to transform it. As before, set the `affinity` parameter to `precomputed`. For clarification, it does not accept the number of clusters as input.
- **Scikit-learn's OPTICS clustering:** Similar to K-Medoids, set `metric` to `precomputed` and use the distance matrix as input for the `cluster.fit_predict` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think PAM and Hierarchical clustering algorithms can be good when your input is a distance matrix. Take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-on-mixed-type-data-8bbd0a2569c3)